# Where is the last red coin in Motos Factory?

Tags: b3313

I am trying to collect the 8 red coins for [Motos Factory](https://b3313.fandom.com/wiki/Motos_Factory) in B3313 v1.0, but I have only been able to find 7. I've found the following red coins:

- At the start of the level behind where you spawn
- In the large conveyor belt room with 7 split paths, take the back path with grid sections above laba
- In the large conveyor belt room, take the back left path that leads to the room with the white coin trap that goes to a jumpscare
- On top of a red box after climbing a pole to the 2nd floor.
- On the 2nd floor, in-between some grey crushers above a green pit
- On top of a grey box in the corner of the same room as the grey crushers. Said box is under the slope leading to the 3rd floor.
- On the 3rd floor, go through a door to enter the Motos's office. Coin is on a box.

Where is the 8th red coin I'm missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The last red coin was in the conveyor belt section. Head down the middle conveyor belt on the right side. The red coin is in a corner next to a metal cap. It's collected 30 seconds into the video below.